# How to distinguish Table from View in Entity Framework 4 T4 script

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an EDMX where I have imported both Tables and Views.  In the T4 script, these are discovered via `foreach( EntitySet set in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>( ) )`.

"container" comes from `foreach (EntityContainer container in GetSourceSchemaTypes<EntityContainer>())`.

I have not found any property of EntitySet that I can use to tell me whether it is a Table or a View.  How can I tell?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the container. `EntityContainer` is general class which can be used for both CSpace (CSDL) and SSpace (SSDL) mapping metadata. CSpace describes your class model (what you see in the designer) and SSpace describes your table model (what you have in the database). Between these two sits CSSpace (MSL) which describes mapping from CSpace to SSpace.

Different space is used for different generators. Class generators use CSpace because they must create classes same as entities defined in CSpace. SQL generators use SSpace because they must create SQL using correct objects from SSpace. CSSpace is never used for code generation and almost whole its implementation is not public.

Information about view is stored in SSpace in `EntitySet`'s `MetadataProperties`. If you are working in CSpace to generate classes you don't have access to this information because entity from CSpace has no knowledge about its storage. Because API for CSSpace is not public it is also quite hard to move from CSpace space to SSpace without using some naming convention (or hardcoded solution) to convert name of the entity to name of the table.